# calling function in an object from another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, prototype

I have two functions here

```
function Preloader() {}
Preloader.prototype = {
    init:function() {
        // do something
    }
}

var preloader = new Preloader();

function Project() {}
Project.prototype = {
    init:function() {
        // do something else 
    }
}

var project = new Project();
```

I want to call project.init() in preloader's init function but obviously

```
project.init()
```

doesn't work 'cause there's no project variable in preloader. How should I call it? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can *pass* the `Project` instance you wish to call `init()` on *to* the `Preloader` `init()` function?

Comment: I need to wait till a tween to end in preloader.init then call project.init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Preloader.prototype = {
    init:function(project) {
        project.init();
    }
}

var preloader = new Preloader(),
    project = new Project();

preloader.init(project);
```